# Glossy materials in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

How can we create glossy effects on materials with three.js like the one on this link?
I am not interested in path tracing (yet :) )

[WebGL Path Tracing](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-path-tracing/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Glossy refers to the ability of a material to reflect light in the specular direction.

In three.js, you can use `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` to do that. For example:

```
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
    color: 0x996633,
    envMap: envMap, // optional environment map
    specular: 0x050505,
    shininess: 100
} )
```

You can also use `MeshStandardMaterial` with an environment map.

three.js r.97

Comment: every day a new mile in webGl / Three.js world.

Comment: but how would you update the variable when needed? something like `.set(50)` ?

Comment: @GiorgiGvimradze I know it's a bit late. I'm not exactly sure what you want, but you can save the material inside a variable `var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({...});`, then change any parameter by setting `material.shininess = 30`. Don't forget to let THREE know that the material needs to be updated `material.needsUpdate = true`